# How much change do I have to make on a Kinect project with SDK version 1.0 to the newest version?

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am currently working on a school project on Kinect passed by my senior. 
I just realized that the version of Kinect SDK was 1.0, whereas the latest is 1.7.
I did a few searches that the old and new version is not that compatible.
Should I install the latest version? Is there any risk of not working out? Sorry for asking stupid question, the deadline is near and I was quite panic

Comment: Why don't you create a backup of what you have and test it?  Any changes there are would be simple enough to change.  At the very most the namespaces and/or method names would be slightly diffferent.

Answer (score 1):

The changes to the SDK between SDK 1.0 and 1.5 where quite significant.  In addition to the namespace change (simple) there were several changes to various functions, enumerations, callbacks, hardware access and how all of that is references.

The latest [Kinect for Windows SDK Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855347.aspx) references version 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7.

At the least, you will have to update namespaces and will have to work your way through the code to update how multiple points of data are referenced.  How `Joints` are accessed comes to mind, but there are plenty of others.  Without knowing what you application does, and not having access to the code, it is impossible to say exactly "how much change" is needed.

If you still have access to SDK 1.0 and it does everything you need it to (for a school project) then you can certainly stick with it.  SDK 1.7 is much more robust and more straight forward.  Updating to the latest SDK may be worth bonus points.

Comment: thxs, I just updated it to v1.6 and it came out to be good. In fact, the debugger will remind about changes in namespaces and it was not difficult to convert.